# Ethereum network and raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am a baby to ethereum blockchain. Is it possible to interact with the  local ethereum network that resides on my laptop from my raspberry pi? I need to connect with the smart contract that is deployed in my laptop from my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either 
1. try having an own node on the raspberry, syncing to the node on the laptop, which will require more resources, or

2. you connect to the node on your laptop from the raspberry, which would mean making the node on the laptop the so called

> RPC Provider

or

> web3 provider

like here: [web3 api](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's helping and it's giving me an idea of how to approach this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nikita - what can be the recommended way(tool) to run the node on my raspberry Pi or in my laptop and to sync these nodes. Please can you give some reference on it

Comment: That depends on what you would like to use it for. Full syncs / archive syncs on the mainnet won't work, too many IOPS required. But if you build a private chain with limited blocksize, you can run archive nodes. In other cases, check if light sync / warp sync (parity) suits your needs, or simply just connect to a node from the raspy instead of having it running an own one (which is the "cooler" thing to do though)